# Add / Divide Numbers in PHP

Tags: php, math, echo, addition, divide

I am working on a Facebook App that needs to be able to average three numbers. But, it always return 0 as the answer. Here is my code:

```
$y = 100;
$n = 250;
$m = 300;
$number = ($y + $n + $m / 3);
echo 'Index: '.$number;
```

It always displays Index: 0

Any ideas?

Comment: So, with your edited version it displays "Index: 450". With casablancas fix for operator precedence, "Index 216.666666667". Are you still having a problem with this?

Comment: Actually.. everything was right. All the numbers in the DB were set to 0! :) Corrected that, but how do I round the result?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$y = 100;
$n = 250;
$m = 300;
$number = ($y + $n + $m) / 3;
echo 'Index: '.$number;
```

Also - you missed `;` in the end of the first 3 lines

Comment: @Zach, no it doesn't.  So probably, `$y`, `$n`, and `$m` aren't getting initialized as you expect.

Comment: @Zachary Brown: copy-paste my code into the blank file and see the result.

Comment: @zerkms, that wokred.. which means that it is an issue with the numbers from the DB. However, I also need it rounded to the nearest whole number. There a PHP way for that?

Comment: @Zachary Brown: just wrap all the expression with `floor()` then

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago: oops, i've read him as "the lowest whole number"... sure, `round()` then

Comment: Im really sorry If my question is dumb, but still shouldnt it display a value? for example: (100 + 250 + 100) = 450. Or am I wrong? Because he missed the formation to get returned the average of the 3, but that doesnt mean maths stop there.

Comment: "shouldnt it display a value" --- display it where and by what?

Answer (score 4):

Your parentheses are grouped wrongly. You should be doing:

```
$number = ($y + $n + $m) / 3;
```

Comment: @Zachary Brown: You're missing semicolons in the previous lines - it won't even parse with that, I wonder how you get a 0.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

You are missing `;` at the end of these lines:

```
$y = 100
$n = 250
$m = 300
```

And to `/` has higher precedence than `+` so you need to do:

```
$number = ($y + $n + $m) / 3;
```